# Ignore Old Cookies ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core

After I updated my asp.net core site (cookie domain is unchanged), previously registered users get error on login and can't login and they need to change their browser to be able to login. Is there a way to tell the app to ignore previous cookies or a workaround?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use a different cookie name?

Comment: @Tseng how is that? I only see domain

Answer (score 0):

No, not directly. If clearing the sessions doesn't help you can simply change the cookie names and then Identity won't attempt to use the old cookies anymore.

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    // default for Core Identity is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.Service
    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.CookieName = "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.Service.V2";
});
```